# Calculated field column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, date, formula

I am trying to compare two date columns in SharePoint. I need to update the created date field to a different date, but only on documents that have a scan date less than the created date. So I have a formula in a date update column thatstates =IF([Scan Date]<[Created],"Yes"), but when I apply it, it says that all of the documents have a scan date less than the created date. So I thought ok, that is not working, I will change it to say if the dates are equal to say “No” and the formula I have is =IF([Scan Date]=Created,"NO","YES") and the results are all “No”.  So the formula only half works. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try ````=IF([Scan Date]<[Created],"Yes", "No")````. When you compare [Date1]=[Date2], most likely the time part of the dates are not equal and giving you all "No"s. Do you have empty [Scan Date] values?

Comment: @MatiurRahman I tried that before and its the same results. It changes all to "Yes" and no, I do not have an empty scan date value. All the fields have a date.

Comment: What's the type of your calculated field? So, if [Scan Date] is less than the [Created] then the formula should return "Yes", otherwise "No", correct? [Created] date is the system date here, right?

Comment: @MatiurRahman- I just created a new calculated column with that formula to return a singe line of text (not sur if that is what you were asking about type of calculated field). And yes that is what I want the formula to do.

Comment: Not sure what is the difference in your environment. It works for me. Let me know if your conditions/column types are different from mine.

Comment: @MatiurRahman my apologies, I forgot to include that I would like it to also say no to the documents that have the same date. So the formula works for the dates that are less than the created date but it does not work for the ones with the same dates. I tried to add = in there but its not working. Do you have and idea how I would generate that formula?

Comment: Updated my response to show how to compare two dates (=). Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: With the = in the formula =IF([Scan Date]=Created,"Yes","No") this is what appears.
10/29/2020 10/29/2020 1:25 PM No
10/29/2020 10/29/2020 1:25 PM No
10/19/2020 10/19/2020 12:29 PM No
10/19/2020 10/19/2020 12:29 PM No
10/12/2020 10/15/2020 7:34 PM No
10/5/2020 10/15/2020 7:33 PM No
They all change. Even if the dates are the same. I would like it to say no on same dates and yes on different dates. No mater what I try <, >,=, <=, >= it doesnt seem to recognize the same dates and gives me all yes or no.

Comment: Since these dates have time, use ````=IF(DATE(YEAR([Scan Date]),MONTH([Scan Date]),DAY([Scan Date]))=DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created),DAY(Created)),"Yes","No")````. See my revised response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me, where
[Scan Date] is **Date and Time** Column,
[Created] is a **System** column shows when items are created and
[ScanStatus] Calculated column outputs **Single line of text**

Does it match your conditions?

```
=IF([Scan Date]<Created,"Yes","No")
```

[image]

---

**Updated the formula**

to show date comparisons:
If column Date and Time format is **Date Only** then `[Date1]=[Date2]`
If the format is **Date and Time** use as shown below:

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR([Scan Date]),MONTH([Scan Date]),DAY([Scan Date]))=DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created),DAY(Created)),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: BINGO- THIS WORKED!! THANK YOU SO MUCH MATIUR! Now I know that the column  format was causing the issue. You just saved me hours of work! I'm new to this SharePoint Admin stuff and all this forum, so if you have a moment I would appreciate it if you could explain to me how you came up with that formula. AGAIN THANK YOU!

Comment: Please mark the questions as answered

Answer (score 0):

I tested with similar setup with Matiur and it also works in my end. Try with the formula below.

```
=IF(([Scan Date]<[Created Date]),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you help Jerry- It was a date and time format that's why it wasn't working. Matuir gave me the updated formula and it worked! Thank you for your time!